# How to create a Julia macro for indexing into nested expressions based on given indices?

Tags: macros, julia

I am trying to create a Julia macro that takes an **`Expr`** and a vector of indices (**`Vector{Any}`**) as input and produces a new expression by indexing into the nested structure based on the given indices.

For example, if the input expression is **`exp.args[1]`** and the indices are **`[2, 5, 4]`**, the output should be **`exp.args[1].args[2].args[5].args[4]`**.

Here is the macro I have so far:

```
macro transform_expr(expr::Expr, indices::Vector{Any})
    transformed_expr = esc(expr)
    for index in indices
        transformed_expr = Expr(:index, transformed_expr, esc(index))
    end
    return transformed_expr
end
```

However, when I try to use this macro, I get an error. Can someone help me understand what might be going wrong or suggest improvements to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: This seems likely to be an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and probably doesn't need a macro at all (an ordinary function would likely do the job). Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish here, what is the original problem you wish to solve?

Comment: @SundarR The actual problem is I am trying to edit an expression(exp). I want to replace some Symbol names in exp. But if I use PreOrderDFS of AbstractTrees, I couldn't able to directly change exp arguments of Symbols. So I created a function to generate tree indices based on order of PreOrderDFS(1 -> [1]  for exp.args[1], 2-> [1,1] for exp.args[1].args[1]). But I couldn't able to generate expression like exp.args[1].args[1] out of indices [1,1] using macro.

Comment: The later problem  will be i couldn't evaluate the exp unless it is a global variablein module.